# shodan.exception.APIError: Access denied (403 Forbidden)

Tags: python-3.x, shodan

Please help, I have the error above when trying to use shodan API with python. I tried using different API key but still has the same issue. I'm using mac os. Thanks[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3oth.png)

I tried to perform a simple search with shodan API.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).